# Как получить порядковый номер кнопки по которой было нажатие?

Tags: javascript

```
<ul class="button">
    <li><button></button></li>
    <li><button></button></li>
    <li><button></button></li>
    <li><button></button></li>
</ul>
```

Подскажите, как определить номер кнопки по которой был сделан клик, на чистом JS?

Answer (score 3):

Примерно вот так.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.list button') // ищем кнопки в элементе с классом list, по аналогии CSS

buttons.forEach((button, index) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => console.log(index + 1))
})
```

```html
<ul class="list">
    <li><button>1</button></li>
    <li><button>2</button></li>
    <li><button>3</button></li>
    <li><button>4</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Как может быть, что тут по кнопке выполнить код этот код работает, а у меня в хроме нет?

Comment: Проверьте селектор класса или укажите какую ошибку выбрасывает браузер ?

Comment: Нет отображаемых ошибок

Comment: Уже обнаружил, в чём было дело. Сначала не заметил, что <ul class="list"> а не "button".